# Сдвиг BottomNavigationView при открытии клавиатуры

Tags: android

При открытии клавиатуры BottomNavigationView сдвигается таким образом

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать, чтобы меню оставалось на месте, а не меняло место?

**UPD**

Manifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="asus.example.com.fitnessapp">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ArticleActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ProgramActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Добавьте `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` вместо `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"`. Если используете `ScrollView`, то вдобавок добавьте в него `android:isScrollContainer="false"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Необходимо добавить в **AndroidManifest** для этой активити флаг:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateAlwaysHidden"
```

Comment: возможно не туда добавил этот флаг, но проблема не решилась. Может зависит от того, что у меня ввод осуществляется во фрагменте?

Comment: @SergeiMikhailovskii я подправил ответ